# Is there a quasi-particle corresponding to sound wave in air medium?

Tags: waves, acoustics, quasiparticles

I have seen many quasi-particle here in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle). Is there any quasi-particle concept for sound wave in air medium?

If it exists, what's the purpose and usefulness of it?

If it does not exist, is there any reason that people do not make such concept?

Comment: try this phonon link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon